# Javascript - Changing my button onclick function after the first function executed

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to build a Trivia game, right now I've one question and 3 answers (radio buttons), the user will choose one answer and then click submit. If it's the wrong answer the button will show "Retry" instead of "Submit.
First I only started to learn Javascript and I'm pretty sure there's a simple/better way to use one button to submit and then "retry" if the answer is wrong. I just created two functions, first **function()** that will check the answer, if it's the wrong answer it'll jump to **wrongAnswer()** This function suppose to change the text of the button, changing the button onclick (so I can increase the number of "clicks") and will check if there's more than 1 click (if true: location.reload) I couldn't think on a better way to let the user try again answering the question (I made the other radio buttons gray after "wrong" answer).

**Also why when I put**

> var clicks = 0;  outside the function it's NaN... Why?

**My main problem, the second click will give me this error instead of increasing the "clicks" (it's not defined on HTML but this's why I change the attribute as you can see in the code**

> Uncaught ReferenceError: wrongAnswer is not defined
>       at HTMLInputElement.onclick (index.html:1)

Though I can see on the button inspect that the onclick is now = wrongAnswer();

**My HTML:**

```
<input class="submit" id="mybtn" onclick="userChoose()" type="submit" value="Submit!">

    <p>Clicks: <a id="clicks">0</a></p>
```

**My javaScript:**

```
function wrongAnswer() {
var clicks = 0;  // for how many button clicks
clicks += 1;
document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;

var btn = document.getElementById("mybtn");
btn.value = 'Try again'; // Will just add a hidden value
btn.innerHTML = 'Try again'; // Even without inner it works ??? (not sure why)
btn.style.fontSize = "x-large"; // Made the text a little bit smaller

document.getElementById( "mybtn" ).setAttribute( "onclick", "wrongAnswer();" );


}
```

}

In the end I'll be happy if someone can explain what I did wrong and if there's a better way instead of doing this to reload the page by clicking the button again after "wrong answer".

```
 if (clicks = 2){
    location.reload;
    }
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have a html page with a button and each time the user answers it wrong, you reload the page? and then it will show retry? Can you tell me when the page is supposed to reload and when it is supposed to show retry? It is not a good idea to reload the page. have you looked into angular or react for front-end?

Comment: Hi, I've HTML page with one button, 3 radio buttons. the page should reload if the user presses on the "Retry" button after the answer was wrong. At the beginning this button text is "Submit", but I change it in the function to "Retry" depends on the user choice. I just don't understand why my button doesn't repeat the wrongAnswer() function after I assigned new attribute to the onclick.

Comment: can you try having 2 buttons? one for submit and other for TryAgain. you hide and show options depending on what the user clicks? if you have a jsfiddle, I can try to take a look.

Comment: How do you hide buttons? I didn't know I can do it. If it's possible I'll create another one, but I also need to understand how to hide the first one and then show the new one. Also, you said "location.reload" isn't recommended, so I need to figure out how to reset the user choice after the wrong answer marked.

Comment: you need to use style.display (similar to what you have here https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_hide_show.asp)
I would recommend you to study angular or react. can you put your code in jsfiddle or something so that someone can run the code.

Comment: Did you get this to work?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much :) I don't know how to mark your answer...

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question here there is an example:

In this example i have a question and 3 radio buttons (answer1, answer2 and answer3).. if the user click on radio button1(answer1) he gets an alert with good job else an alert with retry and the button value is retry!. The user when click on the reTry the page is reload...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<title> test</title>
<style>
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function userChoose(){

    //control the value button if it is submit or retry
    let btn=document.getElementById('mybtn');
    if(btn.value=="Submit!"){

        //user have to answer
        let answer= document.getElementById('answer1');
        if(answer.checked){

          alert('good job!');
        }
        else{

            //wrong answer
            alert("Retry!");
            document.getElementById('mybtn').value="Tryagain!"
        }

    }
    else{

        //call function wrongAnswer()
        wrongAnswer();

    }
  }
  function wrongAnswer(){
    location.reload();
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>QUESTION....</p><br>
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="answer" id="answer1" value="a1">answer1<br>
  <input type="radio" name="answer" id="answer2" value="a2">answer2<br>
  <input type="radio" name="answer" id="answer3" value="a3">answer3<br>
</div>
<br>
<input class="submit" id="mybtn" onclick="userChoose()" type="submit" value="Submit!">
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps